# Inserting byte file inside html <img> tag

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm using Angular 2 to retrieve image from backend. My response looks like that

```
{ AcceptRanges: 'bytes',
LastModified: 'Sat, 09 Dec 2017 17:06:46 GMT',
ContentLength: '462882',
ETag: '"c0ff5b060c2da69deff97065d43e3645"',
ContentType: 'application/octet-stream',
Metadata: {},
Body: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 02 00 00 64 00 64 00 00 ff ec 00 11 4475 63 6b 79 00 01 00 04 00 00 00 3c 00 00 ff ee 00 0e 41 64 6f 62 65 00 64 ... > }
```

Is there any chance I can insert that thing directly inside html img tag, or should I start off by converting it to say base64? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob in your GET-Request settings and convert it later to base64 encoded source. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

a solution is to use Base64 Image source, that should return encoded base64 from backend. forExample:

```
img.src = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP//ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==";
```